# Set WordPress to Create different images format later, not during upload

Tags: images, uploads

I have an issue with the upload time. I allow users on my site to post step by step tutorials, and they often contain a lot of images. That makes the tutorial posting time very long, sometimes even up to five minutes. 
I'm trying to fix this by reducing the number of images created at upload. Since WordPress creates at least 3 or 4 formats for one uploaded image, an upload of 10 pictures is actually an upload of 30 or 40 pictures which would explain the load time.

How could I set WordPress in a way that it will create this post formats later, but not during upload ? 
Or does anyone has an idea on how to reduce upload time regarding images ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Optimize your images (<150 KB each image). I upload 50-60 images in a tutorial too and it does not take any longer than 2 mins. Also it could depend on your connection speed and server too.

Comment: Also if you do not require and use different image sizes then you should disable those from media settings in WordPress admin. Setting width and height to 0 for a thumbnail size will disable it from thumbnail generation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Roberthue , I have many questions for your since we have the same use. I can't really ask users to reduce their image size, they won't post if I do so. 
Which hosting service do you use ? Do you use a form plugin to let your users post tutorials ? Do you do on the fly images optimization with a plugin ?

Comment: @Roberthue I already disabled the medium size as I need the thumbnail and large size.

Comment: I use 2GB VPS on Linode. If you are on shared hosting then you should consider upgrading your server. For frontend posting I use contact form 7. You should reduce number of plugins used and keep those which are absolutely necessary. I also use `EWWW Image Optimizer` to optimize images on the fly. There may be a plugin slowing your website down. Try to identify the culprit with query monitor or p3.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `thumbnail generation` is the issue for such a long upload/processing time? You can try disabling all thumbnails temporarily and test if this is what causing the issue.

Comment: Would you mind giving me your site's URL so I can see how you set the form please ? I've been struggling with this issue for a while. To use Linode, I'd need technical knowledge on how to maintain a server, and I don't have this knowledge. Would you say that the professional plan at Pagely compares to what you have at Linode in term of power ? I'm thinking of moving my site at Pagely. I'm going to look into my plugins to see which one is slowing the site

Comment: WordPress also creates, medium, large, and other custom sizes depending on the theme. So that makes a lot of images, it's not just the thumbnail

Comment: Yes, WordPress create custom image sizes and those are also called thumbnails. You must disable default sizes from WordPress admin and custom sizes from theme and then try again and see if your are still facing long processing time. You must identify your issue first. & Pagely server would be fine.